# Unable to add the keywords on the component in the classify window?

Tags: content-delivery, core-service, keyword

I have keywords in a category when I select the component and click on the classify a classify window open and it showing me a category and keywords but when I select the keyword  there is a insert button in the classify window but it is not enable so I am not able to added the keyword what is the problem and how I do this please tell.

Comment: Can you share some details on your Schema, what are the field properties for the Keyword field exactly (multiple value etc.)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most likely reason is that the Schema used by the Component does not actually have a list field that accepts Keywords from the Category you are in.

Comment: I have a list field on my schema and this schema attach to the component when I attach this to the component no item is showing in the list. but when I click classify my category is showing there and the keywords are also showing but when I select the keyword that time insert button not enable .

Comment: Did you select that Category in the Schema, though?

Comment: yes there is showing category I checked the category checkbox and select the category from the list list-type "dropdown list" and height "1" and field type is "text" my Schema type is "Schema" and root element name is "content" and I created field in the design part of schema

Comment: In that case check the security on the Category and that your Keyword isn't Abstract.

Answer (score 3):

I think you might be looking at the left, tree panel. That panel is used for navigation only, you can't select keywords from there. What you need to do is select the category in the left panel and then select keyword in the right panel.

It might also be the case that your keywords are abstract.

Answer (score 2):

You have two types of keywords; Abstract keywords and Concrete keywords; You can only assign Concrete keywords.

- News (categorie)

  - Sports (abstract)

    - Tennis (concrete)
    - Basketball (concrete)

This can be done by selecting in the structure the abstract keyword, then on the right panel the concrete keywords show up. These can then be selected and inserted.